# Fetch from database and serialize row by row millions of records

Tags: java, oracle, performance, hibernate, serialization

I want to query a table from database, like

```
select * from TABLE1
```

TABLE1 has about 15 million records.
There is a hibernate class Table1.java

```
@Table(name = "TABLE1")

    public class Table1 implements Serializable{

        @Column(name = "ID")
            private Long id;

        @Column(name = "Name")
            private String name;

        .. more columns

        .. getters and setters


    }
```

If I query using hibernate and return the entire list, it'll take up a lot of memory.
Instead I want to fetch each row, serialize the object into a file, then take the next row and serialize it and so on. My goal is to serialize the data into files, so that I don't have to keep the result list in memory.

In order to save the memory , I get the results as ScrollableResults. I need to serialize the results from ScrollableResults to file and I need to do it row by row so that I don't keep anything in memory.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            StatelessSession statelessSession = HibernateUtil
                    .getSessionFactory().openStatelessSession();
            statelessSession.beginTransaction();

            ScrollableResults results = statelessSession
                    .createSQLQuery("select * from TABLE1").setCacheable(false)
                    .setReadOnly(true).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

            results.close();

            statelessSession.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Pretty much , I need to read from database and serialize it right away without keeping in memory. How to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe add `.setFetchSize(fetchSize)` after `.setCacheable(false)` would be helpful ?

Comment: I could add that but I am looking to how to convert  result from ** ScrollableResults results ** to type Table1 and then serialize it without using memory

Comment: I need to stream data directly from database to file